# Запустить видео в сафари, javascript

Tags: javascript, видео

Помогите решить проблему и возможно ли ее решить. Суть проблемы такая. Есть события нажатия на кнопку в форме, по этому нажатию должно происходить запуск видео. Все бы хорошо, но предположим необходимо выполнить асинхронную функцию, пусть после нажатия в CB будет setTimeout 1s. Его убрать нельзя, как не потеряв токен действия запустить это видео??! Т.е в Safari из за политики он теряет клик и не запускает его.

*Псевдокод*

```
let btn = document.getElementById('button');
let videoElement = document.getElementById('video');
btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    videoElement.play();
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: ```the request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context```

Comment: С чем связана необходимость выполнения асинхронной функции? Что мешает выполнить её заранее, перед кликом? Или параллельно клику?

Comment: Попробуйте при клике запустить видео, сразу же поставить на паузу и воспроизвести анимацию, а уже после анимации воспроизвести видео второй раз

Comment: как вариант это сработает, но не представляется возможным по ряду причин...на самом деле, код гораздо сложнее и вызов самого videoElement.play() это колбэк а вернее даже это модуль и код посылаемый пожет быть любым...в данном варианте это запуск видео, не знаю на сколько понятно...суть состоит в том, можно ли это сделать в таком виде както...или отказываться от setTimeout вынеся его отдельно, что не очень желательно